# try/catch clauses in switch statements

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement

When using a switch statement, should i catch exceptions that are relevant to a case within that case? or catch all relevant exceptions outside the switch statement? ex.

```
 try{
 switch(){
                   case 1:
                   case 2:
                   case 3:
         }
 catch(WrongDataException ex{sysout(ex);}
```

Or else:

```
switch{ 
case 1: 
try{
}catch(WrongDataException ex{sysout(ex);}
break;
case 2:
try{
}catch(YouNeedToPayAttentionException ex){sysout(ex);}
```

?

Comment: Definitely the latter if there are different types of Exceptions that occur.

Comment: If i did the first way I couldn't just catch all the possible exceptions?

Comment: If you don't care from which `case` an exception arose, they by all means use one `try...catch` around the whole `switch` statement.  If you have to handle exceptions from specific cases differently, then put `try...catch` inside those cases.  Both ways are perfectly valid, it just depends on what your particular needs are.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer 'wrapping' the switch statement in a try/catch clause.

The main thinking is

1. Express logic in a straight-forward way via switch clause
2. **If** there is an exception you intend to handle, wrap it in a try/catch block.